# Debugging a mysql connection

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, linux-networking, amazon-rds

I am trying to figure out how to diagnose a mysql connection issue.

- When I run a group of queries locally on my machine it takes about 1s to run.
- When I run that same group of queries on an AWS machine that has an RDS-backed mysql instance, it takes roughly 8x longer, 8s to run. The machines are roughly comparable in size.

Two questions here:

- How would I go about diagnosing what the issue is? It isn't the query or database, as they are the same in both cases. For example, what are some tools or commands that I could use to pinpoint the possible issue?
- What are some ways to speed up the connection from my ec2 server to the rds server? I was under the impression that an rds-backed instance was relatively the same in speed (if not faster) than having the db on the server.

Comment: Just a clarification thing: When you say you run a group of queries on your local machine - does that mean the actual DB server is also on the local machine or are you somehow accessing the RDS from the local machine?

Comment: @MrMajestyk no local machine + local database. vs. AWS ec2 instance + rds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use profiling.

`set profiling=1;`

Then do your queries in the same session.
Then look for profiles:

`show profiles;`

And display them:

`show profile for query X;`, where X - is a number of profile.

```
mysql> show profile for query 2;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000042 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000011 |
| init                           | 0.000008 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000081 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000017 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000143 |
| init                           | 0.000038 |
| System lock                    | 0.000021 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000020 |
| executing                      | 0.000021 |
| end                            | 0.000013 |
| query end                      | 0.000010 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000027 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000082 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000198 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
15 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```